# 'Encapsulation Vs Performance' trade-off in a lockable linked list

Tags: java, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, abstraction, encapsulation

Main purpose of *encapsulation* is to protect in-variants of any `class`(in java).

[Here](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/tree/master/JavaCode/src/cs61b/homework4) is the complete code for `class DList`/`class lockDList`/`class DListNode`/`class LockDListNode`.

`class DList` and it's subclass `class LockDList` has following invariants.

```
/* DList invariants:
   *  1)  sentinel != null.
   *  2)  For any DListNode x in a DList, x.next != null.
   *  3)  For any DListNode x in a DList, x.prev != null.
   *  4)  For any DListNode x in a DList, if x.next == y, then y.prev == x.
   *  5)  For any DListNode x in a DList, if x.prev == y, then y.next == x.
   *  6)  size is the number of DListNodes, NOT COUNTING the sentinel,
   *      that can be accessed from the sentinel (sentinel) by a sequence of
   *      "next" references.
   */
```

But the user of `class LockDList` and `class DList` can pass/receive the wrong list node. This leads to **breaking of encapsulation** because of the only reason i.e., **in-variants are not protected**, because user can pass wrong node to `class DList` or `class LockDList` For example, below is the public method `next` in `class DList`.

```
public DListNode next(DListNode node) {
      if ((node == null) || (node.getNext() == this.sentinel)){
          return null;
      }else{
          return node.getNext();
      }
  }
```

Most of the production code try introduce such O(1) implementation, keeping `item` of `class DListNode` as `public`.

Is there a design decision that can be suggested to maintain encapsulation without performance hit?

Comment: Can you explain why you think this "breaks encapsulation", or what your criterion for a better encapsulated solution is?

Comment: @DocBrown  Answer to your first question is addressed by editing the query. Criteria is to make sure that correct node is passed to `class DList` and `class LockDList`. My understanding is, by ensuring correct node being passed, my code will be perfectly encapsulated.

Comment: Well, I see what you are after, but can you explain which of the invariants you listed becomes broken in your example exactly?

Comment: Invariants **2,3,4,5** break. because it does not make sense to say, `For any DListNode x in a DList`, Because that node `x` may not be actually part of that `DList`, if the user passes node of `list1` to `list2` by saying `list2.someMethod(nodeOfList1)`. Most of the production codes implement such linked lists O(1) for better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't expose what the user doesn't need to know.

If the main interface is just `DList`, then you should not expose `DListNode` to the user of your class(es). You may make `DListNode` a private class, which is manipulated internally by `DList` only.

In the case of iterating through your list, e.g. `next()`, you may move this to an enumerator or iterator like class, which contains an associated list. This way you hide the `DListNode` class and there's no way for the user to accidentially pass nodes from one list to another.

If you have no way of hiding such classes, you must add some sort of ownership in these implementation classes and check them, to be sure no accident happens.

Comment: nodes are passed/received by user to update `item` in node. check the access level of `item`.

Comment: That is IMHO the better design. A `DListIterator` can provide the same access to the items as a `DListNode`, but it eliminates the necessity to provide a `next` method in the `DList` class itself, which removes the OPs problem. And, it does not add a memory penalty as in my suggestion. The only advantage of my solution is that it modifies the existing API only a little bit.

Comment: @OlafDietsche I think you are talking about such [implementation](https://github.com/shamhub/Java_programming/blob/master/JavaCode/src/JavaCollections/DblyLinkList.java). But how do I introduce `lock` field in new class `LockDListNode`.

Comment: @overexchange I don't understand this question. If you really need to lock a node, you can just add some sort of lock member. With Java, you don't need an explicit lock member, because you can use the node object for locking. See [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html), [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) and http://stackoverflow.com/q/3047564/1741542

Comment: @OlafDietsche Ah, I forgot to share the homework [question](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw4/readme.pdf). Please read Part III here.

Comment: @overexchange You can just add a boolean member `nodeLocked`, which will be set in `lockNode()` and checked when the `remove()` method is called.

Comment: @OlafDietsche add in which class? Do I need two more classes? `LockDListNode` and `LockDList`?

Comment: @overexchange When you look carefully at Part III, it talks about `LockDList` and `LockDListNode` classes. I would simply add a `locked` member to the `LockDListNode` class. But I think other implementations are possible too. Maybe you should ask a new question for this topic.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Please find the new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268191/how-to-write-constructor-in-derived-inner-class) as recommended

Answer (score 2):

Your major problem comes from the user passing a node that do not belong to the list, as you said in your [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/293260/encapsulation-vs-performance-trade-off-in-a-lockable-linked-list#comment607161_293260):

> [...] if the user passes node of list1 to list2 by saying
>   list2.someMethod(nodeOfList1)

You could try to avoid letting the user manipulate nodes, in which case you would need an indirect way to access them, but this pushes the problem one step further. What you need to do in this case is the check that the node belongs to the list. When this is true, then your invariants are satisfied.

You can add an `owner` reference from `DListNode` to `DList` and initialize it during construction: for example, `dlist.insertBack(Object)` would return a `DListNode` which references `dlist`. The `owner` is not mutable and can be made final public (or, use a getter).
Then, you must check that `this == node.owner` when manipulating nodes inside list operations, or throw a runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute `myDList` to the class `DListNode` and implement a method like `next` in the following manner:

```
public DListNode next(DListNode node) {
   if (node == null)
      return null;
   if(node.getMyDList()!=this)
      throw // ...some exception here
   if (node.getNext() == this.sentinel)
      return null;
   return node.getNext();
}
```

That will not add a significant performance penalty, but it adds a memory penalty, because every node has to hold an extra reference now.

EDIT: you can even avoid the memory penalty when you follow the suggestion of Olaf Dietsche. Introducing an iterator class will avoid the necessity for a `DList.next()` function at all, and the corresponding `next` function of the iterator will need no parameters, which eliminates the possibility of passing any inconsistent values.

Comment: @overexchange: not sure I understand what you mean with that question.

Comment: Does it make sense to define *abstraction* at class level? If yes, How do I interpret *abstraction* in this case with these `class DList`, `class LockDList` `class DListNode`  `class LockDListNode`? Did you get my question? am trying to understand OOPS concept *abstraction* with this example

Comment: Each of the classes form an abstraction on its own, and when you group them together, for example, into a library or package, you might create a "list package" or something like that, which is an abstraction, too, but on a different level. Does this help?

Comment: When you say, "each of the class form an abstraction", I would like to understand, in what sense, does  each class form an abstraction? What does it mean to say, DList form an abstraction?

Comment: A `DList`class is an abstraction for the concept "double linked list", and a `DListNode` is an abstraction for an element of such a list. Do you have a different kind of meaning in mind? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29

Comment: I heard that abstraction separates interface from implementation.am not sure, what is interface and implementation in these two classes DList and DListNode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26794/discussion-between-doc-brown-and-overexchange).